# How to read COleSafeArray efficiently

Tags: c++, com

I find it hard to find clear examples that would explain how to read a `COleSafeArray`...

So I have an object that returns through a member function a `_variant_t` that is actually a `COleSafeArray` . I want to read it's element and make sure I'm not leaking memory...

Here is a kind of sample code. I am just trying to read the ifrst element of the array which I assume to be a long. There's more data in the array.

```
class ExampleObject
{
  _variant_t GetArray();
};

//...
long Read(ExmapleObject* ptr)
{
  COleSafeArray the_array = ptr->GetArray();


  VARIANT value_temp;
  VariantInit(&value_temp);

  long index = 0;
  the_array.GetElement(&index, &value_temp);
  long my_result = value_temp.lVal;

  return my_result;
}
```

Is there anything wrong in this code that may generate memory leaks ?

Comment: Yes, if the array doesn't contain variants of the right type then you'll get a garbage value and leak the element.  Check value_temp.vt and use VariantClear() to release memory.

Comment: so whatabout the `COlseSafeArray` functions `Destroy` `DestroyData` `DestroyDescriptor` and `Clear` ? Also which types need a call to `VariantClear` ?

Comment: @jules: don't forget to award the bounty to Roman R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficient read of `COleSafeArray` contents is about reliability and performance.

To read reliably, avoid junk and leaking, you should check types of the array itself and the elements. The `.vt` field tells you the type of array, which might be array of specific [fixed] type, or array of `VARIANT`, which in turn might embed sub-arrays.

You have options to get individual elements using `GetElement`, in which case [if the data element is a string, object, or variant, the function copies the element in the correct way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221255%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and hence you are responsible for clearing the copy. To have it done for you by a wrapper class, get your elements into `CComVariant` class variable, as opposed to `VARIANT` struct (`~CComVariant` will clean things up for you).

Or, otherwise having type checked you can Lock/Unlock array and obtain direct access to elements managed by the array. You might prefer this method for performance because you lock once and copy if needed, as opposed to having locks and copies per element in previous access option.

`~COleSafeArray` destructor clears the elements of the array, so you don't have to destroy/release them explicitly.

Comment: I don't understand the Lock/Unlock issue. Also what's the difference between CComVariant and _variant_t ?

Comment: `1` - Variant need data locked when accessed. `GetElement` does it for you automatically, every time you access individual element. Another option is to explicitly `Lock` once and have a raw pointer to access the data without per-element locks. `2` - both are classes (just different ones) with destructors to clean up the data.